# NGXS Inactivity Timeout

Tags: angular, ngxs

In an Angular project. I'm new to NGXS and trying to convert an NGRX effect that watched all actions and if an action wasn't a logout action, it reset a timer. If the timer expired before another action, it automatically executed a user logout. I'm not certain how to achieve this in NGXS. Here's my NGRX effect:

```
@Effect()
extendApplicationTimeout$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
    switchMap((action: Action) => {
        if (action.type !== 'LogoutUser'){
            return timer(this.APPLICATION_TIMEOUT_TIME)
        }
    }),
    map(() => new LogoutUser())
);
```

Comment: Please mention your technology.You are using angular

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Meta Reducer: https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/meta-reducer

```js
import { getActionTypeFromInstance } from '@ngxs/store';

export function extendApplicationPlugin(state, action, next) {
  // Use the get action type helper to determine the type
  if (getActionTypeFromInstance(action) !== LogoutUser.type) {
    // do timer stuff...
  }

  // return the next function with the next state
  return next(state, action);
}
```

You would wire it up like this:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NGXS_PLUGINS } from '@ngxs/store';

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([])],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NGXS_PLUGINS,
      useValue: extendApplicationPlugin,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You wouldn't have to do it this way. You can use `getActionTypeFromInstance(action)` in your own plugin too.

If you need to dispatch an event, you'd need to use `useFactory` with `deps` and inject `Store` or use the injector to get a reference to `Store`.

Haven't tested this, and I don't know if it will work, hopefully it pushes you in the right direction:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NGXS_PLUGINS, Store } from '@ngxs/store';

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([])],
  providers: [
    {
        provide: NGXS_PLUGINS,
        useFactory: extendApplicationPlugin,
        deps: [Store],
        multi: true,
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Implementation

```js
import { getActionTypeFromInstance, Store } from '@ngxs/store';


export function extendApplicationPlugin(store: Store) {
  return function extendApplicationPlugin(state, action, next) {
    // Use the get action type helper to determine the type
    if (getActionTypeFromInstance(action) !== LogoutUser.type) {
      // do timer stuff...
      // store.dispatch()
    }

    // return the next function with the next state
    return next(state, action);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I use a metareducer how do you dispatch an action (to logout the user) once the timer expires? There is no constructor to inject the store. Can I call an action directly?


    `if (getActionTypeFromInstance(action) !== LogoutUser.type) {
      setTimeout(() => {
           this.store.dispatch(new LogoutUser);???
        }, timeout);`
    `}`

Comment: @markelc that's an angular DI issue you would want to figure out, I'll update my example...

Comment: Whenever I try to inject the store, I get a circular dependencies error. I thought I might be able to do "return next(state, LogoutUser)" but that fails too. Not sure why I can't substitute actions.

Comment: @markelc you might try to start with a very simple project and try and reproduce what you're doing.... I'm using the `Store` as a dependency in multiple providers that use `useFactory`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried this solution in a clean project with the same errors:

Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! InternalStateOperations ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! StateFactory ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule

This is a Nativescript ng project, but I don't see why that would change anything.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to listen to the NGXS action stream to manage this timer at the top level.

You could create an injectable service that you load into the `app.module` `providers` via the `APP_INITIALIZER` token.

```
@Injectable({provideIn: 'root'})
export class AppTimeoutHandler { 
    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private store: Store) {
  ...// subscribe to `actions$` and then reset timer
  ...// when timer expires, store.dispatch(.. new LogoutAction())

  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution, but I get a circular dependencies error when I add it to the the providers.